# entity onetomany ..annotation exception

Tags: hibernate, entity, one-to-many, many-to-one

I have two classes mapped OneToMany, ManyToOne, and i get exception:

org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: 
entity_package.TicketEntity.ownerEntity in entity_package.UserEntity.ownedTickets

here is the code :

public class UserEntity implements Serializable {

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="ownerEntity")
public List<TicketEntity> getOwnedTickets() {
    return tickets;
}
public void setOwnedTickets(List<TicketEntity> tickets) {
    this.tickets = tickets;
}
```

and ...

public class TicketEntity implements Serializable  {

```
private UserEntity ownerEntity;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="owner_id")
public UserEntity getOwner() {
    return ownerEntity;
}
public void setOwner(UserEntity owner) {
    this.ownerEntity = owner;
}
```

whats wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The property name is `owner` as defined by the annotated getter. Use:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="owner")
public List<TicketEntity> getOwnedTickets() {
```

Comment: thanks that works =) but why ? my object is called ownerEntity, not owner ... or i should use what is defined by getter ?

Comment: Great! So you can accept the answer (the V button near my answer). And welcome to Stack!

Comment: Oh, that's because Hibernate uses the XXX from the annotated getXXX getter as the property name. It lets you choose whatever name you want for the actual class field or even do some logic that generates a `UserEntity` according to some conditions.